# Plotting in matplotlib from a generator

Tags: python, matplotlib, iterator, generator

Is it possible to produce matplotlib plots from a generator without specifying beforehand the total number of plots? For example:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def gen():
    for i in range(10):
        yield np.random.random(100)

# Here something magic to avoid setting number of rows 
fig, ax = plt.subplots(undetermined, 1) 
g = gen()
for i, arr in enumerate(g):    
    ax[i].plot(arr)
```

The idea is to generate different plots without removing previous plots until `StopIteration`. Is there something to allow this behavior?